# How to scroll with jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make some buttons work here.
http://www.sepulturaimpex.ro/portofoliu is the website.

When i click left/right buttons i'd like to move from project to project exactly

The images are random width.

How can i achieve that?

Here is the script i'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".prev").click(function () {
        $(".p_horizontal_wrap").animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=700"
        })
    }), $(".next").click(function () {
        $(".p_horizontal_wrap").animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=700"
        })
    })
}),
```

Comment: sorry.. the website is https://www.sepulturaimpex.ro/portofoliu-constructii-civile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question; if the images are random width, then you cannot scroll w/ a fixed width

I think your best bet is to look ahead and find the x position of the next object, then scroll to that. Depending on your markup, you may need to keep track of the object index you're scrolling into view.

Your next button (and your next/prev could be the same) would look like this:

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var targ = /** find out the next item to be shown **/
    var left = $(targ).position().left;
    $(".p_horizontal_wrap").animate({
        scrollLeft: left
    });
});
```

Comment: if i'd make all images in that https://sepulturaimpex.ro/portofoliu-constructii-civile/ a fixed width -say 800px;   what do i have to change in the script? Thx a lot for answering

Comment: you would still have a scrolling problem. even though you are setting to 800px; I'd imagine you are making these images responsive, so that they'll show appropriately on mobile, tablet, desktop viewports; so, you'll still want to know the horizontal x position of each element. on a phone, your next image may start at 321px, on a desktop, it may be 801px.

Comment: Hi. I found another gallery which i can use.. but i stii have a problem on google chrome..is does not center the front image.. here is the site https://www.sepulturaimpex.ro/portofoliu-constructii-metalice/  Can u please help?